# Run the application at startup Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, autoload

The application performs the function of fixing time on tasks for users. Is located on the desktop window, which is always open, the icon is not displayed in a task bar. There is an icon in the system tray, by pressing on which leaves from the window of the screen (as Action Center in Windows 10). The application uses the Internet.

I use this method when start main window:

```
public bool SetAutorunValue(bool autorun) {
    Assembly curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
    try {
        if (autorun)
            reg.SetValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name, curAssembly.Location);
        else
            reg.DeleteValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name);
        reg.Close();
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The method adds to the Registry, but the launch will not start.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: At the start I did not try to catch the error. On debug the value is put in the registry without errors

Comment: Yes, but you can catch your apps startup errors. Im thinking its trying to start too soon and running before users login

Comment: After a user logs I saw running processes, it was not there. You do not know how it is possible to delay the start?

Comment: What does your app do? Is it a user app or more like a service such as antivirus checking? does it need desktop? we are playing a lot of guess work here.  You've put it in the registry to run on startup, you havent said to run when a user logs in, so, that assumes it doesnt really need a desktop to talk to to show anything, to interact with in any manner.

Comment: Update description

Comment: The app then "is an icon in the system tray". Which doesn't exist when the app starts up, as the user hasn't logged in yet and so there **is** no system tray, and the app fails to start. You need to start your app after the user has logged in.